# Display images in Django

Tags: django, image, imagefield

I have a django app which allows users to submit an image with it. Right now my model looks like

```
class Posting(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    images = models.ForeignKey(Image, null=True)

class Image(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/",null=True, blank=True)
```

and I am trying to display the images in my template however I cannot seem to get it to work. I have gone though countless stack overflow posts and haven't had any luck. In my template I have

```
{ for post in postings }
    <img src"{{ post.image.url }} #and many variations of this
```

however other seems to display the url. The url seems to always be blank. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try this - <img src="{{ post.images.img.url }}" ... >
because your Posting model has 'images' named attribute of Image model.

Comment: `<img src="/{{post.images.img}}"/>` Try this. I guess the problem is with the relative path. Append '/' to the path.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is how i got it working.

**settings.py**

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = (
BASE_DIR
)


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**models.py**
...

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='img')
```

**urls.py**(project's)

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**template** (.html)

```
<img src="{{ post.image.url }}" alt="img">
```

Comment: what is `static` for in your **urls.py**?

Answer (score 5):

Do something like this. This code is working in my app.

views.py:

```
def list(request):
  images = Image.objects.all()
  return render(request, "list.html", {'images': images})
```

list.html:

```
{% for i in images %}
    <img src="{{ i.image.url }}" width="500px"/>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

The template tag should be:

```
<img src="{{ post.images.img.url }}" ... >
```

Answer (score 1):

You should expect something akin to:

```
{% for post in postings %}
  <img src="{{ post.image.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

There are a couple of caveats here --

- Images are served as a file, whatever is serving your application (runserver, nginx, apache, etc.) needs to have the ability to route that file.
- You must ensure you are building the context for the template engine to use. It will silently fail on values that it cannot find in context.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that but no luck. Will this still work if each postings has a `foreignKey`? This is a one-to-many correct?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be trying to follow a video tutorial series by Corey Schaefer.  If so, my suggestion won't help, but if not, Corey Schaefer has a video that covers exactly what you're trying to do at 
https://youtu.be/FdVuKt_iuSI?list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p.

You have to set quite a number of settings and override some defaults.  The django documentation has two ways of doing it, one for development on localhost and another for production:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/