# Django Model serving Media Files

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have two models: `Packages` and `Images`. `Images` has many to one relation with `Packages`. `Images` table has a foreign key `package_id`. I have to display the attributes `country`, `price` of `Packages` with one image related to the package. There can be many images related to a single package however, I have to choose only one.

The table looks like:

`Packages`:

- id
- country
- price

`Images`:

- id
- url
- package_id

My code looks like:

Views.py

```
def index(request):
    featured = Package.objects.filter(featured=True).order_by('-pub_date')[:4]
    featured_packages = []
    for item in featured:
    image = item.packageimages_set.all()[1]
    data = {'package': item, 'image': image}
    featured_packages.append(data)
    context = {'featured': featured_packages}
    return render(request, 'tours/index.html', context)
```

Index.html

```
{% for item in featured %}
<p>Country: {{item.package.country}}</p>
<p>Price: {{item.package.price}}</p>
<p>Image: <img src="{{item.image.url}}"></p>
{% endfor %}
```

Everything seems fine I get the URL. However, I am not getting the output. The output looks like this:

[image]

Where are my errors? I am not being able to display the image. And is there anything more efficient to do the above task?

Comment: It seems like a directory path error. Have you set up static and/or media file directory in settings.py? Here is Django's documentation on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360395/display-images-in-django

Comment: What is your MEDIA_URL setting? And what have you done to actually serve images at that URL?

Comment: STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' 
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') This is what I have. Every thing seems to work on another page where I have a little different method to fetch the content . However, it doesnt seem to work on this page. @DanielRoseman

Comment: Yes! I have set up everything thats needed. Everything works fine in another page. I shows up images. But I am not being able to display in this page. @Magnus

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code:

```
featured_packages.append(data)
```

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'data'

Answer (score 0):

I actually tried different thing and finally landed to this solution.
Views.py:

```
def index(request):
    packages = Package.objects.filter(featured=True).order_by('-pub_date')[:4]
    featured_packages = []
    for package in packages:
        image = package.packageimages_set.all()[1]
        data = {'package': package, 'image': image}
        featured_packages.append(data)
    return render(request, 'tours/index.html', {'featured_packages': featured_packages})
```

And a little changes to Index.html:

```
{% load static %}
{% load thumbnail %}


{% for item in featured_packages %}
{% thumbnail item.image.url "1170x480" crop="center" as im %}
<img src="{{im.url}}" width="{{im.width}}" height="{{im.height}}" alt>
{% endthumbnail%}
{% endfor %}
```

I dont know how but this actually fixed my problem. Here is the [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYuo5.png). I am getting some encrypted file names and the pictures are actually loading. 
Is it the thumbnail ? I am using sorl.thumbnail or I dont think "load static" was making any effect because I tried to load the file without it. And it worked completely fine.