# How can i display either video or image based on file type in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

A part of my website allows users to upload pictures and videos, just like facebook or instagram, a user can upload either video or picture and it will be rendered on the template depending on the file extension type. Whatever the user uploads either picture or video should be rendered on the template. Am using Django.

[models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNJuX.png)

[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k7Y1.png)

[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBtyW.png)

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360395/display-images-in-django

Comment: Please see attached screenshots above

Answer (score 0):

First You Need To Join Your Media directory to your app

Here is the Way You Can Do That:

First You Need To Add This in Your `Setting.py`

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASEDIR,'your folder directory')
```

## for example app/media or something

Then You Need To Create Media Url Here is The Way:

Then You Need To Add in your root and app urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('your_url_link', views.your_view_name,name='your_url_name'),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Then You Need To Add This in Your Html File

```
<img src='{{ context.Image.url }}'>
```

**#Context mean your returning object Dictionary In Image Add Your Model Image Field Name**

You Can See More Details Here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url

Comment: thanks for your comment.. am trying to display image on the template when the user  uploads and image and display video on the template when the user uploads a video... something like an if else statement to handle the two processes

Comment: You Can Use This Code And You Can See It Will Work