# Django load an imageField in a template

Tags: python, django, django-models

Essentially what I'm trying to do is load the thumbnail image from my Post model in my template.

`models.py`

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    published = PublishedManager() # Our custom manager.

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(name="photo", upload_to='thumbnails/', null=True, default='default.png')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail', args=[self.publish.year, self.publish.month, self.publish.day, self.slug])
```

`views.py`

```py
class PostListView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.published.all()
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 3
    template_name = 'blog/post/list.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        obj = Settings.objects.get(pk=1)
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["blog_name"] = getattr(obj, "blog_name")
        context["footer"] = getattr(obj, "footer")
        context["description"] = getattr(obj, "description")
        context["keywords"] = getattr(obj, "keywords")
        return context
```

I added `<img src="{{post.thumbnail.url}}" alt="{{ post.title }}">` to my template to try and load the image but no luck.  I can access the image if I load the path manually and i already added MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT to my `settings.py`

If this question can be improved please let me know as I am knew to django.

`template`

```html
<header>
  <a href="../../../.." id="home-btn"></a>
  <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {$('#top-bar').width(Math.round($(document).scrollTop()/document.body.offsetHeight*100*1.1)+'%');});
  </script>
  <div id='top-bar'></div>
  <h1 id='title'>{{ post.title }}</h1>
  <p id='author-info'>Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}</p>
</header>
```

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360395/display-images-in-django) please

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I would check first is to make sure the URL is actually showing up correctly in the template. You can do that by just creating a dummy span like this:

```
<span>{{ post.thumbnail.url }}</span>
```

Put that somewhere, render the page and see what you get. Ensure that the URL is the correct URL. Sometimes when you're messing with media URLs and roots, things get a bit wonky.

UPDATE:
Based on your recent edits, I see two red flags: One is that you've got your body up in your header section. Two is that it doesn't appear that you're iterating through the list of objects that are being passed as context by your ListView. Your listview, as i interpret it, is passing a list of posts. If that's the case, your code should look something like this:

```
<header>
  <a href="../../../.." id="home-btn"></a>
  <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {$('#top-bar').width(Math.round($(document).scrollTop()/document.body.offsetHeight*100*1.1)+'%');});
  </script>
</header>
<body>
    <div id='top-bar'></div>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <h1 id='title'>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <p id='author-info'>Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}</p>
        <img src="{{ post.thumbnail.url }}">
    {% endfor %}
</body>
```

Still, there is something a bit off about your whole HTML document. You'll need to add in DIV elements or grid table elements to more appropriately render the above stuff.

Comment: If you're getting an empty span element, that likely means that Django is having trouble rendering that element.  Can you share a snippet from your template? Are you iterating through all of the posts?: {% for post in posts %}...?

Answer (score 0):

Another thing: Since your'e using a list view, you might want to post a portion of your template code here in your question. As a list view, you have to ensure that you're properly looping through the object you're sending to the template as context.

Is everything else showing up in your template rendering as you intend? Is it just the image that isn't showing properly?