# Django display images from database

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to display a list of images on my development page but the only images I am getting are this [white-blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE55N.png) image.

Here are my Django codes

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS =[os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media_cdn')
```

**views.py**

```
def imgdownload(request):
    allimages = ImagefieldModel.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/show.html',{'images': allimages})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ....
    ....
    path("show/", views.imgdownload, name="imgdownload"),
    ....
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**models.py**

```
class ImagefieldModel(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200) 
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to = "media")

    class Meta:
        db_table = "imageupload"
```

**show.html**

```
{% extends "main/header.html" %}

{% load static %}
 

 {% block content %}
      <head>
        <title>Django Display Images</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <div class="container">
          <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Title</th>
                  <th>Image</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              {% for img in images %}  
                <tr>
                  <td>{{img.title}}</td>
                  <td><img src="/{{ BASIC_DIR }}/{{img.img}}" width="120"/></td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %} 
              </tbody>
          </table>  
          </div>
      </body>
 {% endblock %}
```

I am not sure what is wrong since I have declared the MEDIA_URL correctly. Some help is much appreciated.

Comment: try ```<td><img src="{{img.img}}" width="120"/></td>```, because Django usually returns the MEDIA_ROOT already attached to the url

Comment: @Jjkivai still no changes sadly. On cmd I get this error "GET /show/media/building.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3635

Comment: according to this post [Display images in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360395/display-images-in-django) it should be ```{{img.img.url}}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% for img in images %}
<img src="{{ img.img.url }}" width="120"/> 
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify `show.html` setting image source as:

```
src="{{img.img.url}}" //will link back to the image file
```